# my custom Theme default.XML is missing sign in on top header

Tags: magento

I am missing "sign in" on top header - however I do have "create an account" 
can someone please take a look at my custom theme XL and suggest what I am missing..I have tried everything.

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">148</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">43</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="footer_links" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="report.bugs" remove="true"/>
    <move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
</body>
```

Comment: What is it a theme for? What platform or programming languages are you using?

Comment: Sorry - this is a custom Luma theme. Magento 2.1.16

Answer (score 0):

Probably authorization-link block have removed from your theme, or parent block / container that have been removed, you can add it manually by adding

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
```

to which container/block that you want to show that block, eg: header.panel